io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException:The exception could not be delivered to the consumer because it has already canceled/disposed the flow
I am using RxJava in my app. Upon making changes to the version code > clearing cache > clearing data > uninstalling > reinstalling the app.
The app goes straight to the HomeFragment after splash with this exception and crashes.
The general flow for the app is Splash > Onboarding > Login > Home.
The exception in logcat states:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
             Process: com.viva.yag, PID: 27013
             io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: The exception could not be delivered to the consumer because it has already canceled/disposed the flow or the exception has nowhere to go to begin with. Further reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#error-handling | android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f140091
                at io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins.onError(RxJavaPlugins.java:367)
                at io.reactivex.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(HandlerScheduler.java:126)
                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:211)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:300)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8503)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:561)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:954)
             Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f140091
                at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:480)
                at android.content.res.MiuiResources.getText(MiuiResources.java:106)
                at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:573)
                at com.viva.yag.source.remote.networkViewModel.NetworkViewModel$makePromotionsApiCall$2.onSuccess(NetworkViewModel.kt:1591)
                at com.viva.yag.source.remote.networkViewModel.NetworkViewModel$makePromotionsApiCall$2.onNext(NetworkViewModel.kt:1639)
                at com.viva.yag.source.remote.networkViewModel.NetworkViewModel$makePromotionsApiCall$2.onNext(NetworkViewModel.kt:1575)
                at io.reactivex.internal.observers.DisposableLambdaObserver.onNext(DisposableLambdaObserver.java:58)
                at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.drainNormal(ObservableObserveOn.java:201)
                at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.run(ObservableObserveOn.java:255)
                at io.reactivex.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(HandlerScheduler.java:124)
                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942) 
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:211) 
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:300) 
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8503) 
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:561) 
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:954)

The code in NetworkViewModel where the logcat points is:
class NetworkViewModel: BaseViewModel() {
       fun makePromotionsApiCall(){
    mDataManager.requestToGetPromotions()
        .doOnSubscribe {
            mGetPromotions.value = ApiResponseObserver.loading()
        }?.subscribe(object: CustomObserver<Response<MainResponseModel>>(){
            override fun onSuccess(t: Response<MainResponseModel>) {
                if (t.isSuccessful)
                {
                    mGetPromotions.value = ApiResponseObserver.success(t.body()?.response)
                }
                else {
                    val error: MainResponseModel? = ErrorUtils.parseError(t)
                    when {
                        t.code() == 401 -> {

                            mGetPromotions.value = ApiResponseObserver.expire(
                                ErrorResponse(
                                    error?.response?.status ?: false,
                                    error?.response?.message ?: Resources.getSystem()
                                        .getString(
                                            R.string.error
                                        ),
                                    t.code()
                                )
                            )
                        }
                        t.code() == 404 -> {
                            mGetPromotions.value = ApiResponseObserver.expire(
                                ErrorResponse(
                                    error?.response?.status ?: false,
                                    error?.response?.message ?: Resources.getSystem()
                                        .getString(
                                            R.string.error
                                        ),
                                    t.code()
                                )
                            )
                        }
                        t.code() == 500 -> {
                            mGetPromotions.value = ApiResponseObserver.expire(
                                ErrorResponse(
                                    error?.response?.status ?: false,
                                    error?.response?.message ?: Resources.getSystem()
                                        .getString(
                                            R.string.error
                                        ),
                                    t.code()
                                )
                            )
                        }
                        else -> {
                            mGetPromotions.value = ApiResponseObserver.error(
                                ErrorResponse(
                                    error?.response?.status ?: false,
                                    error?.response?.message ?: Resources.getSystem()
                                        .getString(
                                            R.string.error
                                        ),
                                    t.code()
                                )
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            override fun onNext(t: Response<MainResponseModel>) {

                onSuccess(t)
            }
            override fun onError(e: Throwable, isInternetError: Boolean, error: CustomError?) {
                mGetPromotions.value= ApiResponseObserver.error(error?.code?.let {
                    ErrorResponse(false,error.message,it)
                })
            }
            override fun onRequestComplete() {
            }
        })
}}


It said  String resource ID was missing check your string resource references

but it is available in strings.xml and getting used in app globally many times

there maybe unescaped characters in the string resource
